# ¿Cómo podría adaptarse este código diseñado en C a lenguaje C++?

Tags: c++

```
#include   <stdio.h> 
#include   <stdlib.h> 
union   persona 
{ 
      char   nombre[15]; 
      char   inicial; 
      int   n; 
}; 
int main( ) 
{ 
     union  persona  per; 
     printf("Escriba  su  nombre:   "); 
     gets(per.nombre);  
     printf("\tSu  nombre  es  %s\n",  per.nombre); 
     printf("\tSu  inicial  es  %c\n",   per.inicial); 
     per.inicial  =  'P'; 
     printf("\nAhora  su  nombre  es  %s\n" ,  per.nombre); 
     printf("\tY su  inicial  es  %c\t%c\n" ,  per.inicial,  per.nombre[0]); 
     per.n  =  64; 
     printf("\nAhora  su  nombre  es  %s\n" ,  per.nombre); 
     printf("\tY su  inicial  es  %c\t%c\n" ,  per.inicial,  per.nombre[0]); 
     printf("El  numero  es  %d\n " ,  per.n); 
     printf("\n La  direccion  de  cada  miembro  de  la  union  es:\n"); 
     printf("%x\t%x\t%x\n" , &per.n,  &per.nombre,  &per.inicial);  
     printf("\n"); 
     system("pause"); 
     return  0; 
}
```

De acuerdo con las indicaciones del ejercicio este código es un ejemplo de como los miembros de una unión comparten memoria, la cuestión es que al momento de compilar el código en lenguaje C++, más específicamente en la herramienta para C++ de Visual Studio, el compilador reporta errores.

Comment: "*el compilador reporta errores*" ¿Qué errores?

Comment: Agradeceré mucho su ayuda

Comment: Me aparece una leyenda que dice: C3861 'gets': no se encontró el identificador

Comment: Lo mejor que puedes hacer es reemplazar `printf` por `std::cout` y `gets` o `scanf` por `std::cin`.

Comment: Ok, intentaré de esa forma

Comment: El ejemplo está mal. No te va a funcionar porque al tratarse de una unión, los tres tipos de datos (nombre, inicial y n) comparten el mismo espacio en memoria. Es decir, que cuando tomas la inicial estás machacando la el primer carácter del nombre. Y cuando lees el valor de n estás machacando nuevamente el primer caracter (posiblemente los cuatro primeros bytes, depende de lo que ocupe un int)